# Postgres SQL Update JDBC Stuck

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, jdbc, sql-update

I'm running the below query through `jdbcTemplate.update()`

```
"UPDATE <tblnme>  as aa set _r=b._r from(SELECT id,parent,LEAD(id,1) OVER (partition by parent ORDER BY id) _r from <tblnme>) as b where aa.id=b.id"
```

This update (1 table - 28 million records) runs fine around 15 min on below m.c config

> SSD 32 GB RAM Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz

but gets stuck in below m.c config

> HHD 32 GB RAM Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz 3.41 GHz

There's no message in postgres server log during the stuck phase. Had to terminate after 4 hrs wait.

have set below in postgresql.conf in both m/c:

> a.    max_connections = 375  b.   shared_buffers = 2500MB  c. max_wal_size
> = 16GB  d.    min_wal_size = 4096MB

What could be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: First install enhanced monitoring system on DB server. You could use prometheus/node-exporter, postgres-exporter. You need to figure out where you are hitting the limit.

Comment: Probably it got stuck behind a row lock. Examine `pg_locks`.